# Debugging with FF3 in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, firefox, ide

I am using Firefox 3 to debug my ASP.NET applications in Visual Studio 2008. How can I configure either FF3 or VS2008 so that when I 'x' out of Firefox I don't have to hit the stop debugging button in Visual Studio? (The behavior you get with IE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this has been to manually attach the debugger to the relevant browser and the aspnet_wp process. When I'm finished, I simply detach all.

Answer (score 1):

Extending upon Raithlin's suggestion, Ctrl+Alt+P is a useful shortcut to bring up the Attach to Process window.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing. I assume you're working with Cassini (the integrated web server).

I've yet to find an answer to that (I just go back to VS and press *Shift+F5* to stop the debugger), but I can tell you that if you check the *"Edit and Continue"* box in the project's properties (web tab), your web server will stop and restart whenever you run your application.

It doesn't solve the whole of the problem, but it suffices for me.